# How to show application version in VS.NET Deployment Project?

Tags: c#, version, deployment-project

I have set up a Deployment Project for my application. The problem is that I want to show application version (eg. MyApplication 1.2.3.1) during installation so the user can see the version before installing.

The only way I can think of is to modify the WelcomeText in Welcome dialog. Is there an easier or more elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use the Windows Installer ProductVersion property for this. If you change the Welcome dialog's WelcomeText property to:

```
The installer will guide you through the steps required to install [ProductName] [ProductVersion] on your computer.
```

Then you can change the Deployment Project's Version property and have the value automatically displayed. Any string-based property can do this; just use the [] syntax to have the value inserted.

For other properties that are provided out of the box, see the [Windows Installer Property Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Where is exactly is the `[ProductVersion]` number set? I have my application `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` properties set and when I build my app and check the details tab it tells me the version is 1.1.0, however, when I run my installer it shows 1.0.0....any ideas?

Comment: It's ok I found it, didn't realise the installer itself is where I set the version I thought it picked it up from the application.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the version number that is set in the executing AssemblyInfo.cs using this code

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()
```

Similarly if you want to get the version number for a specific assembly you can use

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly([type in my assembly]).GetName().Version.ToString()
```

You could then change the welcome text automatically at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. However in Deployment Proejct - User Interface I have something like this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/SetupAndDeployment/userInterfaceWindow1.JPG

So I don't see the possibility to custom modify the dialog boxes or enter any C# code.