# How to use AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute in Deployment Project

Tags: c#, assemblyinfo, deployment-project

I have a C# Deployment Project, for which I would like to change the display during the installation version of the `X.X.Xa` (marked with the letter will be the next version of the test).

For other projects can be done by attribute "`AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute`" in "`AssemblyInfo.cs`". Unfortunately, the Delployment Project does not have the possibility to add the file, and version numbering assumptions there can be only numeric values​​.

Is it possible to somehow add the letter described the version of the installer, so that when you install the correct version to appear?

Comment: You should be able to use the Windows Installer ProductVersion property for this.Check this answer of Andy Hopper http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222840/how-to-show-application-version-in-vs-net-deployment-project#comment3329425_3222990

Comment: Ok. I found the solution. You can not add letters to the version number, but you can just change the name of the application to the `MyApplication v.X.X.Xa` and changing the guid cause, it will be seen as a different version than the `X.X.X`. Unfortunately, in the Add / Remove Programs versions of both applications are presented as `X.X.X`
Is there a way that appeared `X.X.Xa` version number?