# How do I show the ApplicationRevision in Visual Studio 2010 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I can see the 140 in my csproj file.
How do I read and display this number in my application.

I tried 
System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString()

But it did not work

And I have one more question, why the related article always said ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed 
But I have to call "System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed"

Did I miss some thing??

Comment: The number I said is <ApplicationRevision>140</ApplicationRevision>

Answer (score 0):

You can get the version number that is set in the executing AssemblyInfo.cs using this code

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()
```

You can get further information about on the above code from the following link:
[How to show application version in VS.NET Deployment Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222840/how-to-show-application-version-in-vs-net-deployment-project)

Comment: When I used "System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();", I got the "1.0.0.0".

Answer (score 0):

Find the file Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs

Manually alter the version

```
// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.3.0.0")]
```

It works!!